# ALTER TABLE dry run with before and after

Tags: mariadb

I have a legacy application running MariaDB 10.5 with some poor database design choices (e.g. financial values stored as VARCHAR(50)) that I am in the process of trying to improve.

For example, I might change a total_amount VARCHAR(50) column to a more sensible DECIMAL with:

```sql
ALTER TABLE orders MODIFY total_amount DECIMAL(12, 2);
```

However, when I do this I sometimes get warnings like the following:

```
Data truncated for column 'total_amount' at row 120058
```

As these don't show until after I've run the ALTER TABLE query, I can't check whether the truncation matters or not. For example, if there was trailing whitespace which has been removed that's fine, but if the numeric value has changed that's a major issue. The vast majority of rows are modified without problems, but I do need to check every row that generates a warning.

Is there a way to ask MariaDB: 'if I ran this ALTER TABLE command, what rows would change and what would the before and after values be on those rows'? Lots of other software has a 'dry run' option which allows me to do this, e.g. I can run rsync with --dry-run and it will tell me what files it would transfer, but not actually transfer them.

I know I could create a clone of the table, ALTER the clone, compare with the original, then delete the clone, but if there's an easier way to achieve this it would save me a lot of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> SELECT CAST('123.777abc' AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS x; SHOW WARNINGS;
+--------+
| x      |
+--------+
| 123.78 |
+--------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                         |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '123.777abc' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Find the value in that row. Maybe it has non-digits; maybe it is bigger than 999999999.99; maybe something else. Meanwhile, check the rest of values; I'm not sure ALTER can do what you are asking it to do.

```
mysql> SELECT CAST('1234567890123.4556' AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS x; SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------------+
| x             |
+---------------+
| 9999999999.99 |
+---------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                    |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'x' at row 1 |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

A comma instead of period:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST('1,2345' AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS x; SHOW WARNINGS;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
| 1.00 |
+------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                     |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '1,2345' |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Silent rounding:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST('1.2345' AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS x;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
| 1.23 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CAST('9.876' AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS x;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
| 9.88 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of casting. It's not quite as clear as a dry run but a close enough approximation for me to find the affected rows. I ended up with:

SELECT
 total_amount,
 CAST(total_amount AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS total_amount_cast
FROM
 orders
WHERE
        total_amount <> CAST(total_amount AS DECIMAL(12,2))